# Get String Value Dynamically

Tags: android, android-intent

I am passing a value from one activity to another through putExtra() and getExtra() and getting value like:

Passing from
**Activity 1:**

```
intent = new Intent(this, blankScrollActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("alphabets", "a");
```

Recieving at
**Activity 2: blankScrollActivity.class**

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
String varName = extras.getString("alphabets");

TextView textView = (TextView) findViewByid(R.id.blankTextView);
```

String Resource **MyString.xml**:

```
<string name="a">My Example 1</string>
<string name="b">My Example 2</string>
```

I want to get the value of string dynamically to assign textView.

Comment: Dynamically means from where?

Comment: dynamic in which manner dude?

Comment: u have to pass just a.Don't keep that in " ".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
String varName = extras.getString("alphabets");

int resId = getResources().getIdentifier(varName , "string", getPackageName());
String data = getResources().getString(resId);
```

This way, you will get the **String resource** that you want based on the `String` value sent from the first Activity.

Comment: that was mistake I corrected in my question, can you please review it again.

Comment: But I want it dynamically. getString(R.string.a) will work. a is not present in Activity 2.

Comment: I want to retrieve value from "alphabets".

Comment: Getting error: 'Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: name is null'

Comment: You get the error because you have put your string resources in a file named `MyString.xml`. Please move them to the `strings.xml` file

Comment: that changed nothing, i tried it putting in main string.xml file, not worth.

Comment: `name is null` where is this `name` variable ?

Comment: name variable is nowhere. i don't know why it is like that. it is headache now.

Comment: I guess it is saying that <String name <== is null

Comment: Thanks for your time.